# Property of fraction of functions

Tags: calculus

For some continuous function $f(x), g(x)>0$ and for some constant $\varepsilon$,

let $h_1(x)={f(x) \over g(x)}$, $h_2(x)={f(x+\varepsilon)\over g(x)}$ and $h_3(x)={f(x)\over g(x+\varepsilon)}$.

**Question**

If $h_1(x)$ is increasing with respect to $x$, then $h_2(x)$ and $h_3(x)$ is increasing with respect to $x$ as well?

**My Attempt**

I conjectured that it is ture.

To show it, I took the derivative of $h_2$ and $h_3$ with repect to $x$, then from the continuitiy of $f$ and $g$, $\lim_{\varepsilon \rightarrow 0} h_2' = \lim_{\varepsilon \rightarrow 0} h_3'=\lim_{\varepsilon \rightarrow 0} h_1'\geq 0 $.

However, in this apporoach, I realized that I cannot show $h'_2, h'_3 \geq 0$ for larger $\varepsilon$.

I'm wondering if there are other strating point with this problem, or is there any hint from property of functional operation to deal with this problem.

Comment: This is not true in general. Let $f(x) = x+1$ and $g(x) = x+2$. Then $h_1(x)$ is increasing. But $h_2(x) = f(x+2)/g(x)$ is decreasing.

Comment: @sudeep5221 Those functions fail to be positive on all of $\mathbb{R}$, though such an example was my first thought.

Comment: Oh my bad, didn't realize they had to be positive for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The conjecture is false.

As a silly example, take
$$ f(x) = x \left( \sin(x) + 2 \right)
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
g(x) = \sin(x)+2. $$
Note that
$$ \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = x, $$
which is strictly increasing.  However, neither
$$ \frac{f(x+T)}{g(x)}
\qquad\text{nor}\qquad
\frac{f(x)}{g(x+T)} $$
is, in general, increasing. [GeoGebra, for funsies.](https://www.geogebra.org/calculator/yw2qj38t)

---

Because I am dumb, I missed one of the hypotheses:  $f(x)$ is not strictly positive in the above.  But replacing $x$ with $\mathrm{e}^x$ should fix that.  [Another GeoGebra plot, just for funsies.](https://www.geogebra.org/calculator/vqyrndwq)  In the plot,
$$ f(x) = \mathrm{e}^x \left( \sin(x) + 1.001\right)
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
g(x) = \sin(x)+1.001. $$
The general idea is that we should be able to take *any* increasing function, then multiply $p(x+T)/p(x)$ or $p(x)/p(x+T)$, where $p$ has some kind of behaviour which brings it close to zero (which is going to have a large effect on the graph).  I've chosen functions which oscillate, but $p(x) = |x|$ would do the job, too.  There are lots of examples.

Comment: +1 Strictly speaking this does not have $f(x)>0$ for all $x$, but if you had $f(x)=e^{x/10} (\sin(x)+2)$ then it would.

Comment: @Henry Oi... yes.  Maybe thrown in $\exp(x)$ instead of $x$...

Comment: It is more obvious with $e^{x/10}$ or $e^{x/2}$ than with $e^x$

Comment: Or if you replace the 2 with something closer to 1.  https://www.geogebra.org/calculator/vqyrndwq